# How to validate person names? - Python/Django

Tags: python, regex, django, validation

**I wish to create a validator for full names for one of my forms.**

Unfortunately I am not sure the best way to go on about is, as it is not as trivial as:

```
if not char in string.letters + " .'":
    raise ValidationError("...")
```

Thought a regex would work, but `\w`, `[:alpha:]`, `[a-zA-Z]` don't really capture special characters.

**Name examples:**

- Tiësto
- Marie Josèphe
- Marie Françoise
- José de Ribas

---

Any ideas?

### Holy... sounds like I opened a can of worms! Thanks for the great answers.

Comment: There was a couple recently that wanted to name their child "4real". So **why** do you need to validate names?

Comment: Why do you want to limit what characters people can use for their name? For example, some languages, when written, have ! in them, as parts of words (not as punctuation). It seems you're making things harder for yourself for no reason.

Comment: Give up.  You can't validate people's names.   There are no rules.  Digits in names (like "He3nry") are rare, but not impossible or illegal.  "The artist formerly known as Prince" is a rather complex name, and his symbol isn't even Unicode.

Comment: @Arkadiy: Isn't it "His Royal Highness King Henry IV"?

Comment: OK, so one of us is going to be beheaded. But which one?

Comment: @Arkadiy: It can't be me.  My name is invalid, it has a punctuation mark in the middle of it.  Therefore, my name is rejected by the software that tracks beheadings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't bother about validating names, I guess there are so many possiblities it is very hard to maintain. If you could come up with a regular expression, I think it would be so generic it wouldn't be effective. The only thing I can think of as valuable is excluding things like `@ # $ % ^`.

Just make sure you are escaping characters, if someone's name is Fooalert('lala'), that's fine, but make sure it's not parsed.

Answer (score 13):

**Don't.**

Please, read this carefully: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good idea.

What kind of names would you like to exclude? There is no international list of allowed characters for names and there is not much reason to disallow specific characters.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of python it might be re.UNICODE you are looking for?

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE